# Define service for all hosts that belong to all the given hostgroups

Tags: nagios

I can not figure out how to create a service for all hosts that are in 2 given hostgroups.

Example hostgroups:

```
oracle: hostA, hostB
prod: hostB, hostC
```

Now I need a service for all hosts that are in both groups. In that case only for **hostB**

I tried to create a service like that. But this will include all prod servers

```
define service {
        service_description             Oracle Filesystems
        use                             Oracle_PROD_Service
        hostgroup_name                  oracle,prod
        check_interval                  3
        check_command                   check_nrpe!check_fs!pkgname:oracle:95:99!!!!!!!
        register                        1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What has worked for me is to use exclusion

```
define service {
        service_description             Oracle Filesystems
        use                             Oracle_PROD_Service
        hostgroup_name                  oracle,!devua
        check_interval                  3
        check_command                   check_nrpe!check_fs!pkgname:oracle:95:99!!!!!!!
        register                        1
}

define service {
        service_description             Oracle Filesystems
        use                             Oracle_DEV_Service
        hostgroup_name                  oracle,!prod
        check_interval                  3
        check_command                   check_nrpe!check_fs!pkgname:oracle:95:101!!!!!!!
        register                        1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is not possible.

**Explanation**

1. Servicechecks need to be assigned to hosttemplates.
2. Hostemplates need to be assigned to hosts.
3. Hostgroups need to be assigned to hosts.

**Example**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Would it be possible to run the same service on all oracle hosts but have different notifications depending if they are in dev or prod hostgroup?

Comment: @Chris There are `contacts` and `contactgroups` that could be assigned to a host see [this](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Storage/3/html/Console_Administration_Guide/Configuring_Nagios_to_Send_Mail_Notifications.html) and [this](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/objectdefinitions.html). Please create another question if it does not work.